# Selecting part of URL for query

Tags: sql

I'd like to select URL values, but only up to the (optional) ? character in each one. I've tried this:

```
select user_id, REGEXP_EXTRACT(properties.client.url,'[^?]*') as url
```

But I get the error `Exactly one capturing group must be specified`. Is there a way to achieve this?

I'd like it to return something like:

```
123, http://www.google.com/hello
```

Rather than:

```
123, http://www.google.com/hello?why
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You can use split function in sql  and can split you string at ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which DBMS you use but error is self-describing. Try using exactly one capturing group **(...)** as error message suggests:

```
select user_id, REGEXP_EXTRACT(properties.client.url,'([^?]*)') as url
```